# Bash I/O redirection through tee

Tags: bash

I want to capture the output from a Bash script both to the console and to a file. I know that:

`script | tee /tmp/file 2>$1` 
works from the command line but I ant to do this within the script itslf.

```
{
...
} > file 2>&1`
```

is a sample of code that does part of what I want but does not allow the output to go to te terminal. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

I have found that

```
{
...
} > tee file 2>&1
`
```

does not work and I was not surprised. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Why did you change `| tee` to `> tee`? The latter will redirect output to a file named `tee`, it doesn't pipe.

Comment: Why are you surprised? You don't have a pipe there.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do:

```
{
...
} |& tee file
```

The `|&` is a `bash` shorthand for `2>&1 |`

Your command

```
<INPUT> | tee file 2>$1
```

is wrong. The redirection need to be done before:

```
<INPUT> 2>&1 | tee file
```

or

```
<INPUT> |& tee file
```

Don't be confused by this basic snippet, where the redirection occurs later:

```
randomNonExixtantCommand > file 2>&1
```